# Node with axios - pipe gets stuck

Tags: node.js, axios, node-streams

I am facing an unexpected behavior when piping a response from axios. I am making a HTTP request that gives me a stream to download a tar file. I use node-tar to extract it. 
I am running this code for a lot of different endpoints, applying the same logic to each one and 99% of them work just fine, and the rest just gets stuck the pipe never ends, letting the process up and running, doing nothing. (each time I run, a different endpoint gets stuck, seems random which one).
To get to this conclusion, I see that the log "start pipe" shows up, but none of the events are reached. Also, if I uncomment the setTimeout line, the code runs just fine.

See below a code example:

```
const response = await axios.get(...);
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('start pipe');
    response.data.pipe(
        tar.extract({cwd: mydir})
    )
      .on('finish', () => {
          console.log('finish');              
          resolve();
      })
      .on('aborted', () => {
          console.log('aborted');
          resolve();
      })
      .on('end', () => {
          console.log('end');
          resolve();
      })
      .on('error', () => {
          console.log('error');
          resolve();
      })
      .on('close', () => {
          console.log('close');
          resolve();
      })

     //setTimeout(() => {
     //  reject(new Error('20 seconds passed and pipe not finished'));
     //}, 20000);
}).then(() => {
   // do something with the extracted files
}).catch((err) => {
   console.log(err);
   throw err;
});
```

What am I missing?

Ubuntu 20.04 / Node - v14.20 /Axios - 1.1.3 / Tar - 6.1.12